# How to create link to user in telegram?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I need to know how to create the link to the user in telegram......

Like

Name:- $name
Username:- $username
Your id:- $userid
Link:- (what to write here)

Any one please help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you just looking for https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/675#issuecomment-435106472 …?

Answer (score 1):

Messages in Telegram are utilizing Markdown. So you can link to a user by id with

`[John Doe](tg://user?id=12345678)`

So to link to the same user anywhere else use

`tg://user?id=12345678`